# Consume Api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, rest

What is the good ways to consume api in react.
i am make file to handle api to get data. And i consume in another file, but that's make the data from api become undefined before return the real.

**Movie.js**

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const apiKey = 'apikey';
const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

const Movie = {
  GetMovieTrends() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`${url}/trending/movie/day?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        .then((response) => {
          setMovies(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }, []);

    return movies;
  },

  GetMovieGenres() {
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`${url}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        .then((response) => {
          setGenre(response.data.genres);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, []);

    return genre;
  }
};

export default Movie;
```

**TrendContainer.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import MovieImage from "./movie/MovieImage";

import MovieTextContainer from "./movie/MovieTextContainer";

import Movie from '../models/Movie.js';

import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

import {
  withStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const WaitForMovie = withStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    color: '#212121',
    width: '64px !important',
    height: '64px !important',
  },
}))(CircularProgress);

const TrendContainer = () => {
  const movieTrends = Movie.GetMovieTrends().results;

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    h1 className = 'heading1 bottom-margin' > Movie Trending < /h1> <
    div className = 'container-movie' > {
      movieTrends === undefined ?
      < WaitForMovie / >
      :
        movieTrends.slice(0, 7).map((movie) => {
        return ( <
          div className = 'wrap-card-movie bottom-margin'
          key = {
            movie.id
          } >
          <
          MovieImage url = {
            `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.poster_path}`
          }
          name = {
            movie.title
          }
          /> <
          MovieTextContainer title = {
            movie.original_title
          }
          idGenre = {
            movie.genre_ids
          }
          /> <
          /div>
        );
      })
    } <
    /div> <
    /div>
  );
};

export default TrendContainer;
```

Comment: Yes, That's the right way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violating the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) in your `Movie` component, the way it is currently setup should never work. The `useState` and `useEfect` hook must always be in the top level of a REACT function, not just a JS function.

But this could be an excellent example to use a custom hook in your application...

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'apikey';
const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

const useMovies = ({apiKey = API_KEY, url = API_URL}) => {
  const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState('');
  const [ genre, setGenre ] = useState('');

   useEffect(() => {
     async function getMovieTrends(){
      let movieData
      try{ 
      movieData = axios.get(`${url}/trending/movie/day?api_key=${apiKey}`)
      }
      catch(error) {
      // don't keep this in production!!!!
      console.log(error);
      }

      setMovies(movieData.data);
      } 

      async function getMovieGenres(){
      let genreData

      try{ 
      genreData = await axios.get(`${url}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`)
      }
      catch(error) {
      // don't keep this in production!!!!
      console.log(error)
      }

      setGenre(genreData?.data?.genres);
      }

      getMovieTrends();
      getMovieGenres()
      }, [apiKey, url]);
 
      return {movies, genre}
}

export default useMovies;
```